# How to install QGIS from source into user space?

Tags: ubuntu, python, cmake

I want to install [QGIS](http://qgis.org) from source on Ubuntu 13.10. (saucy). into `~/bin`. There is Python 2.7.5+ installed. Therefore, I cloned [the repository](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS) to my machine and checked out the `master` branch. First I did what [the QGIS documentation](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/qgis/QGIS/master/doc/INSTALL.html#toc10) recommends:

1. `$ export CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/bin`
2. `$ cd QGIS`
3. `$ mkdir build-master`
4. `$ cd build-master`
5. `$ ccmake ..`

CMake stops with the following error message:

> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but
>   they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set
>   and tested correctly in the CMake files: PYTHON_LIBRARY
>        linked by target "qgispython" in directory /home/jjd/QGIS/src/python
>        linked by target "python_module_qgis_analysis" in directory /home/jjd/QGIS/python
>        linked by target "python_module_qgis_core" in directory /home/jjd/QGIS/python
>        linked by target "python_module_qgis_gui" in directory /home/jjd/QGIS/python
>        linked by target "python_module_qgis_networkanalysis" in directory /home/jjd/QGIS/python

Second try following the [advise of Secagy](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1005204#p1005204) ...

1. `$ export CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/bin`
2. `$ cd QGIS`
3. `$ mkdir build-master`
4. `$ cd build-master`
5. `$ ccmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/bin/python2 ..`

This time CMake stops with:

> BINDINGS_GLOBAL_INSTALL: Install bindings to global python directory? (might need root)

Running the above command with `sudo` does not make a difference.
In the following I tried various build flags inspired by different posts **without success**.

**References:**

- [CMake error: PYTHON_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND while compiling QGIS [Solved]](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=128582)
- [Building QGIS on Ubuntu 13.04](http://nyalldawson.net/2013/04/building-qgis-on-ubuntu-13-04/)

---

### Solution

Actually, the message *"BINDINGS_GLOBAL_INSTALL: Install bindings to global python directory? (might need root)"* shown at the bottom is **not an error** but a **help message**. So after supplying the include and library paths I could continue by pressing <kbd>g</kbd> in the ccmake wizard to start the generate task.
Here are the steps (customize the paths for your system!):

1. `$ cd QGIS`
2. `$ mkdir build-master`
3. `$ cd build-master`
4. `$ ccmake ..`
5. In the wizard set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to `/home/user/bin/qgis`. Make sure to append `qgis` here!
6. In the wizard set `PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH` to `/usr/include/python2.7`. Should be already set.
7. In the wizard set `PYTHON_LIBRARY` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so`.
8. Press <kbd>c</kbd>
9. Press <kbd>g</kbd>
10. `$ make -j2` The number should correspond to the number of processors in your machine.
11. `$ make install`
12. Add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/bin/qgis/lib` to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` and re-source the shell.
13. Start QGIS from `~/bin/qgis/bin/qgis`.
14. You can also create a `.desktop` file as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508043/how-to-create-a-desktop-entry-for-an-application-located-in-the-user-space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the ccmake step there are two PYTHON related paths:

the header files:

```
PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH (with me pointing to: /usr/include/python2.7)
```

and the libs:

```
PYTHON_LIBRARY (with me pointing to: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so)
```

of course pick the right paths in your own situation.

Comment: Same paths on my system. So I tried `ccmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python2.7 ..` but the problem remains.